# div height: 100vh versus 100%

Tags: safari, height, flexbox

in **SAFARI 8** if you scroll down on a regular site, like facebook.com for example, you will notice that its content is faintly visible behind the semi-transparent menu bars at the top of the page.

i am trying to recreate this for my site. i have four independently scrolling columns, each with a varying quantity of images.

a mockup is here ---> http://mnml.cc/flex/index.html.

i would like to see these images faintly behind the menu bar, but i cannot figure out how to achieve that, and still keep the columns scrolling independently.

in this (failed) mockup, you can see the images behind the menu, but the entire page scrolls as one unit ---> http://mnml.cc/flex/fail.html.

i *think* it has something to do with the container's height -- "vh" versus "%" -- but i can't figure out what goes where. any advice would be greatly great appreciated.

many thanks and warmest regards, **David.**

Answer (score 1):

Using your first mockup as a reference, remove the bottom padding from your .container div. The padding is preventing the scrolling content from reaching the bottom of the window, meaning there's nothing behind the footer to be seen.

```
.container {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

You can now make your footer semi-transparent. For example:

```
.footer {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the reply Phillip, but i am not asking to see the images behind the footer - i am asking how to see them behind the default browser menu header at the top of the browser window itself. this request applies to safari 8 only, as it is the only browser (that i know of) with a semi-transparent menu header.